# Every vector space $X\ne 0$ has a Hamel basis. Look for upper bound for the chain.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, solution-verification

> *Every vector space $X\ne 0$ has a Hamel basis.*

*Proof.* Let $M$ be the set of all linearly independent subsets of $X$. Since $X\ne 0$, it has an element $x\ne 0$ and $\{x\}\in M$, so that $M\ne \emptyset$. Set inclusion defines a partial ordering on $M$. Let $C\subseteq M$ a chain, I must prove that $C$ ha an upper bound. We define $$B_0=\bigcup_{B\in C} B.$$ It is clear that $B_0$ is an upper bound with respect the partial ordering above defined, remains to prove that $B_0\in M.$

> *Proof. $B_0\in M$*
>
> Let $x_1,\dots,x_r\in B_0$ such that $x_1\ne x_2\ne \cdots\ne x_r$, then exist $B_1,\dots, B_r$ such that $x_1\in B_1,\dots, x_r\in B_r$, since $C$ is a chain every two elements of the $C$ are comparable and then we can always write $B_{i_1}\subseteq B_{i_2}\subseteq \cdots \subseteq B_{i_r}$ where $(i_1,\dots, i_r)$ is a permutation of $(1,\dots, r)$. Therefore $x_1,\dots, x_r\in B_{i_r}$ are linearly independent and thus $B_0\in M$

> Question. Is the above proof correct or have I not made enough considerations?

Comment: Writing "$x_1\neq x_2\neq\cdots\neq x_r$" does not convey what you think it does. It only asserts that $x_1$ is different from $x_2$, that $x_2$ is different from $x_3$, etc. But it would not disallow, for example, $x_1=x_3$. The correct way to say that they are all deftorent from each other is to say they are "pairwise distinct".

Comment: Proof of what? You certainly have not proven the statement that every vector space has a Hamel basis. You've barely proven that a set satisfies the hypotheses of Zorn's Lemma so far...

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks for the comment. Now, if we suppose that the $x_i$'s are "pairwise distinct", the proof relating the fact that $B_0\in M$ it's correct? My problem is to prove that $B_0\in M$.